# How do I make a number of milliseconds into a timespan for use in Google Charts?

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, timespan, timeofday

I have a column that is number of milliseconds that I'd like to use in a Google Charts chart to represent a duration. How do I turn that number into a time span?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Google Charts, a time span can be represented using the `timeofday` type, which will allow you to add two times and get a third, and make charts automatically format things properly. A `timeofday` is actually an array with four elements: hours, minutes, seconds, and (optionally) milliseconds. See [this page](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference)'s explanation of the `timeofday` under the `type` property for a DataTable's `cols`.

Each field of the `timeofday` has to be within the bounds of that that type of increment; you can't dump your whole timespan into the milliseconds field and call it a day, because anything over 999 is out-of-bounds.

You can use this function to turn a millisecond time span into a `timeofday`:

```
function toTimeSpan(milliseconds)
{
    var timespan = [0, 0, Math.floor(milliseconds / 1000), milliseconds % 1000];

    // Minutes
    if (timespan[2] >= 60)
    {
        timespan[1] = Math.floor(timespan[2] / 60);
        timespan[2] %= 60;

        // Hours
        if (timespan[1] >= 60)
        {
           timespan[0] = Math.floor(timespan[1] / 60);
           timespan[1] %= 60;
        }
    }

    return timespan;
}
```

A caveat: I don't think a `timeofday` will allow you to hold a span greater than 24 hours. If you need that functionality, you may need to use a `number` column and write your own formatting.

Answer (score 2):

To expand on Kenny's answer, if you input your data as milliseconds, you can use a DataView to convert that to a `timeofday` data type:

```
var timeFormatter = new google.visualization.DateFormat('HH:mm:ss.SSS'); // set this pattern however you need to format your time display
var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
view.setColumns([/* columns before timeofday */, {
    type: 'timeofday',
    label: 'Time of Day',
    calc: function (dt, row) {
        var timeOfDay = toTimeSpan(data.getValue(row, /* time column index */);
        var formattedTime = timeFormatter.formatValue(timeOfDay);
        return {v: timeOfDay, f: formattedTime};
    }
}, /* columns after timeofday */]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using as `asgallant` answer, that expanded the answer from `Kenny Dewhirst` I ended up doing something very similar but instead of using the function `toTimeStamp`, I used the `new Date(milliseconds)`. Code below using livescript.

```
   function millisToDate dt, row
      date = new Date(dt.getValue(row, 0))
      dateFormatter = new google.visualization.DateFormat({pattern: "EEEE d 'de' MMMM 'de' yyyy, H:mm"});
      {v: date, f: dateFormatter.formatValue date}

   view = new google.visualization.DataView data
     view.setColumns([/* columns before timeofday */, {
     type: 'datetime',
     calc: millisToDate
    },  /* columns after timeofday */])
```

**NOTE**: Using `type: 'date'` made that the horizontal axis did not displayed the hours in case the graph show one day data. Changing to `datetime` fixed this.